# Is it possible to construct a state for harmonic oscillator given the mean energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator

The harmonic oscillator is defined by the mean value energy 
$\langle E\rangle=\frac{2}{3} \hbar\omega$. Can we have a wavefunction which describes such a state?

Any help is appreciated. Is it possible to have such state, as we know the energy is $E=\hbar\omega(n+\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: Energy eigenstate, no. It is clear what is the spectrum of a QHO.

Comment: Dear Zarko, Many thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general
$$
\psi(x)=\sum_n c_n \psi_n(x) \tag{1}
$$
where $\psi_n(x)$ are eigenstates with eigenvalue $(n+1/2)\hbar\omega$.  The average energy of the state in (1) would be
$$
\langle E\rangle = \sum_n \vert c_n\vert^2 (n+1/2)\hbar\omega \tag{2}
$$
so you need to find any set of numbers $c_n$ such that the right hand side of (2) gives $2\hbar\omega/3$, subject to the normalization constraint that $\sum_n\vert c_n\vert^2=1$.  Indeed there is at least one solution, which you can find by yourself.

Comment: Many thanks, your answer is logical, Would you please give me more insight, Do you mean a superpostion of eigenstates can create such mean energy value ?